# What’s the meaning of “value is in the eye of beholder”?

Tags: meaning

I [recently asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OskKN.jpg) about the use of on the beach in the phrase "Value (worthiness) is on the beach?"

I got the comment

> Value is in the eye of the beholder.

What’s the meaning of “value is in the eye of beholder”?

Comment: Don't post images of text. Instead write out the important text.  Can you link to the original question?

Comment: @James K I’m shy because I got 3 downvotes on the original question…

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665821/does-property-or-quality-have-also-position

Comment: Did you try searching for "eye of the beholder"? I just tried, and at least three of the top 10 hits were references explaining what it means.

Comment: @IMSop I thought it’s not idiom because he used “eye” not “eyes”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well-known proverb which states that ["Beauty is in the eye of the beholder."](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beauty+is+in+the+eye+of+the+beholder) "Beauty" is not a physical quality like size or weight; it is a subjective thing, and therefore a thing that one person considers "beautiful" another person might think is "ugly." The only *definition* of "beauty" is when someone looks at something and says "That is beautiful." In other words, it is only defined by its being sighted ("in the eye") by a person ("of a beholder").

"Value is in the eye of the beholder" is not an established idiom or proverb, but by following the same format as "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder" the meaning is immediately clear: Like beauty, the concept of *value* is not an intrinsic property of an object. Value is defined by what someone is willing to pay for something, and what you would pay for a ball may not be what your neighbor Bob is willing to pay.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

An entirely equivalent proverb is "one man's trash is another man's treasure". That the utility ('value') of a thing is an entirely subjective quality. It may be because the two are in very different economic situations so the item is commonplace to one while unusual to another, or one may have knowledge the other does not. Or any number of other reasons that they judge the thing differently.

Answer (score 0):

The "beholder" is one who looks at something. The value of the thing being looked at depends on the person looking.
If I don't value it, it has no value to me.
That also means that things are valued differently by different people, which is the point of the saying.